Sign of canonical commutator
In quantum mechanics, the canonical commutator relations are:
\begin{equation}
 \left[\hat{x}_{i},\hat{p}_{j}\right] = i\hbar\delta_{ij}
\end{equation}
Is there a physical reason why they have a plus sign instead of a minus sign? What consequence can one expect if they were $\left[\hat{x}_{i},\hat{p}_{j}\right] = -i\hbar\delta_{ij}$ instead?

Consider to not use \hat over an object with index...

It is a matter of convention. In fact, some do texts choose momentum operator as $\hat{p}_x=i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, whereas others choose $\hat{p}_x=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, leading to a different sign of the commutator. This is closely linked to the choice of sign in the complex exponent in forward and reverse Fourier transform $e^{\pm ikx},e^{\pm i\omega t}$ (A common wisdom is that this chocie is different in QM and E&M). The convention with $[x,p_x]=i\hbar$ seems more common (at least in English-speaking physics.)
Remark
To quote Wikipedia:

In quantum mechanics, the canonical commutation relation is the fundamental relation between canonical conjugate quantities (quantities which are related by definition such that one is the Fourier transform of another).

The Fourier transform in question is
$$
\psi(x)=\langle x|\psi\rangle = \int dp \langle x|p\rangle\langle p|\psi\rangle=
\int dp e^{i\frac{xp}{\hbar}}\frac{\tilde{\psi}(p)}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}
$$

What are the texts that choose the opposite sign?

@Prahar I don't remember - my QM dates a few decades back. But as a student I borrowed from library several textbooks (not in English) and some of them did define the commutator differently (I had been also forewarned by my prof.) The point is, it is a matter of convention, there is no physical reason behind this choice. But once the choice is made, it has to be applied consistently throughout.

Of course, I agree. I have just never seen any text working with the opposite convention so I was simply curious.

I extremely doubt the existence of such texts. AFAIK, the entirety of the physics community had followed strictly Dirac's convention of $p=-\mathrm i\hslash\nabla$, but there are plenty of people who choose to write $[p,x]$ as opposed to $[x,p]$, leading to them having a minus sign difference.

@naturallyInconsistent see my comment above - you seem to suggest that I lied? Anyhow, this is beyond the point, as far as physics is concerned.

No, I am not suggesting that you lied. But having decades between then and now, I think you misremembered it. And I already agreed with you that this is down to convention.

@naturallyInconsistent I've seen the strangest and weirdest conventions applied here and there, so I can at least imagine that such books/texts exist.

@TobiasFünke written by physicists or by mathematicians?
